# Any examples that a function on a subset of a manifold cannot be smoothly extended?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Let $U \subseteq M$ be an open subset of a manifold $M$, and $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(U)$ be a smooth function on $U$.

1. In general, can we extend $f$ to a smooth function $g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$?
2. However, is there any example of $U$ and $f$, such that $f$ does not extend to a smooth function $g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$? Please give the example.
3. If $supp(f) \subseteq U$ is not closed in $M$, is there any example that $f$ extends by zero to a smooth function $g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$? Please give the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to 1. is no. Consider $f(x)=\dfrac1{1-x^2}$ on $U=(-1,1)\subset\Bbb R$.  With regard to 3., the definition of support makes it a closed subset, does it not?

Comment: Since $f$ is defined only on $U$, it's support will be closed as a subset of $U$ and may not be closed in $M$.  For instance the support of $f$ it could be all of $U$, which is open as a subset of $M$.  To answer $3.$, one can take $f$ to be a bump function on $M$, then define $U$ to be the interior of the support of $f$.  In this scenario, the support of $f$ will be open in $M$ and $f$ will extend by $0$.

Comment: Fair enough @DWiggles.

Comment: @DWiggles But we require $supp(f) \subseteq U$,  what do you mean "define $U$ to be the interior of the support of $f$"? Could you give the example more details (e.g., what are your bump function and $U$)?

Comment: @AnalysisNewbie: $U$ is a closed subset of $U$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Well. I define a test function $f(x) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)$ on $U = (-1,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R} = M$, and extends by zero to $g(x) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ and $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}/(-1,1)$. Is this a proper example for 3.?

Comment: Yes, looks good.

Comment: @AnalysisNewbie That's exactly what I had in mind.  Starting with $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the support of $g$ is $[-1,1]$ and the interior of the support if $(-1,1)$.  Defining $U$ as the interior of the support and $f:=g|_U$, it's clear that $f$ extends to $0$ on $M$ and that $supp(f)=U$.  You can do the same thing starting with any bump function on any manifold.